# caching a Rest request

Tags: rest, jersey, osgi

I have a situation where I have a post rest request from another server inquire a customer information including a UID and other information like customer ID.After the response with customer info, I get a second request with same UID to request payment to the same customer. I want to cache this UID and the other information from the first request to be able to identify which second request belong to which customer.

Could anyone help me using jersey to implement this situation?

Comment: Please try to make an attempt at the problem yourself, then post it to your question with any specific questions you have. We do not give out complete solutions or chunks of code.

Comment: You shouldn't do that in REST. The request should have all information needed to process it correctly.

Comment: I know ,but I have to calculate the minimum payment for this customer in the first request and send it back before processing the second request with the payment and it will be overhead to send the same information twice through network.Also, I don't want to save the information from the first request unless the second request succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Pedro, each request should be contains all data required to process the request.

If both request contain the UID and the UID can be used a key, then caching customer info based on the UID (for performance consideration maybe?) is acceptable. But this is a pure cache problem, not a Jersey problem.

If by example, the customer info is fetched using JPA, second level cache could cache this.

If the info is fetched by other means, consider using Guava Cache.
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

You can add to the cache manually (using the cache "asMap"  ) or use a cache loader. It will load and return data if not available in the cache, or return it from the cache if available in the cache.

Guava cache contains all kind of goodies: size based eviction, time based eviction, etc.

Guava cache is easy to use, lightweight and production ready. You can easily wrap a Cache instance into a singleton and share it across request.

Comment: Thanks @filipd, I'm using Spring Data JPA and I don't want to hit the DB many times and at the same time ,don't want to save the information from the first request unless getting and succeed in responding to the second request.So, I want to temporary save information getting it from the first request beside the customer info from DB.